# Mini private key with character "l"?

Tags: private-key, physical-coins

When trying to redeem a btcc chip I noticed a bad encoded mini private key. One of the character is "l". Anyway has seen this before? I guess these keys are also base58 normally?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the digit 1, the uppercase i, and the lowercase L?

Comment: Hi Pieter, I tried I and i (but aren't these excluded as it is base58?).

Comment: It's not a 1 neither...

Comment: Please remove the link; it contains enough of your private key to make brute-forcing it worthwile.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: it appeared to be an "i" but the private key showed it as "l".

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard to brute-force

```
static const char* base58 = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
static void mini ( )
{
  char* x = "S6c56bnXQiBjk9mqSY*******NzrRy?";
  QByteArray xx ( x );
  char* n = xx.data ( );

  for ( int i0 ( 0 ); i0 < 58; i0++ ) { n [18] = base58 [i0];
    for ( int i1 ( 0 ); i1 < 58; i1++ ) { n [19] = base58 [i1];
      for ( int i2 ( 0 ); i2 < 58; i2++ ) { n [20] = base58 [i2];
        for ( int i3 ( 0 ); i3 < 58; i3++ ) { n [21] = base58 [i3];
          for ( int i4 ( 0 ); i4 < 58; i4++ ) { n [22] = base58 [i4];
            for ( int i5 ( 0 ); i5 < 58; i5++ ) { n [23] = base58 [i5];
              for ( int i6 ( 0 ); i6 < 58; i6++ ) { n [24] = base58 [i6];
                const MyKey32 sha ( MyKey32::sha256 ( xx ) );
                if ( sha.constData ( ) [0] == 0 )
                {
                  const QByteArray temp ( xx.constData ( ), 30 );
                  const MyKey32 priv ( MyKey32::sha256 ( temp ) );
                  _trace ( QString ( "%1 %2" )
                     .arg ( priv.toStringWif ( false ) )
                     .arg ( priv.getAddressHashClassic ( ).toString ( ) ) );
                }
              }}}}}}}
}
```

Comment: Might be but I'm not a coder and I don't understand your snippet. Anyway, it's just one character that isn't correct and I wonder how in earth this is possible. I will try to brute force manually :-)